# Bought an album on Xbox Music, can't get it to show up my Windows Phone 8 device

Tags: sync, music, xbox-music

I've got a Lumia 820, and I just bought The Bones Of What You Believe, the fantastic debut album from CHVRCHES. It's playing fine through Windows 8.

If I go into the Music app on the phone and go to 'New', all the individual tracks from the album are showing up there, coverless.

[image]

If I go into the store > music, and find the album, each track says 'in collection, buy'.

[image]

However, there's no listing in artists, albums or anywhere else. On the Windows 8 app I've created a playlist with all the tracks, gone into the phone and checked 'Connect with Xbox Music' (this was unchecked before). No playlist is showing up either.

This is really frustrating. I just want the album in the artist / albums! How do I do that?

Comment: Have you tried a full power down and restart of the phone?

Comment: Tried that just now, no help.

Comment: mmmmm, Is the country chosen in regional settings in Windows 8 matches the country settings in your windows phone?

Comment: actually no... I changed it recently to debug something... changing it back now.

Comment: Did you find the album after you change it back and restart the device?

Comment: No. There's still no sign of it.

Comment: Does your phone have the GDR2 update, it's supposed to fix a few issues with Xbox Music?

Comment: I'd never checked for updates before today. Ran a check, and sure enough there were three Windows phone updates and a Nokia update. I let them work their magic, restarted phone and hey presto, still no CHVRCHES in my artists.

Comment: GDR 3 is now out. Have you got that update installed on your phone?

Answer (score 1):

I contacted MS Support, and after trying several things that didn't work (resetting my password, disconnecting from my MS account and reconnecting, turning off and on cloud sync etc) I finally resolved the issue with a hard reset of the phone.